# Method XXX(String, String, Long) passes constant String of length 1 to character overridden method

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have this method:

```
private String generateDocumentKey(String year, Long version) {
    StringBuilder idKey = new StringBuilder("");
    if (Objects.nonNull(version)) {
        idKey.append(year);
        idKey.append(VERSION);
    }

    return idKey.toString();
}
```

but SonarQube reports this error:

```
Method XXX(String, String, Long) passes constant String of length 1 to character overridden method
```

in the line

```
idKey.append(VERSION);
```

Comment: what you show is not a method, it's a conditional block.

Comment: To get better (if any) answers you probably want to add more context to your question ([MCVE], a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which others could use to actually reproduce same problem you are describing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the constant `VERSION` is currently 1 character long and its type *could* be changed to `char` instead to be more efficient.

It doesn't make sense in the long term (version number will get longer in the future releases), but SonarQube is just a dumb tool and you always have to judge its suggestions by yourself.